# Who is the man with facial deformities in Mad Max: Fury Road?

Tags: character-identification, mad-max-fury-road

WARNING, SPOILERS AHEAD

**1st and 2nd screenshots:**

At the end of *Mad Max: Fury Road* is a scene where they get back to the citadel, and the nurses turn on the water.  It then zooms on the people down below as they rush toward the water, and one of the people is this striking man with deformities on his face.  You can also see him in another screenshot at the end, between Imperator Furiosa and Capable.

**3rd screenshot:**

But, as I re-watched the movie, I noticed another part at the *beginning* of the movie.  It's where Max is first caught by the War Boys, and he's trying to get away from them. During that part, he has several flashbacks from his past — the ones with the ubiquitous little girl — but also one with this same man.  It's very quick, but it's there.

##### Do we know who this guy is?

Screenshots of the character:

[image: screenshot of the character]
[image: screenshot of the character]
[image: screenshot of the character]

Comment: Wow. How did I miss that guy? I don't think much of that is effects.. he lives quite close to where I use to work, and I recognise him immediately because he looks like that, in real life - minus all the pimples and boils.

Answer (score 10):

His name is [Shyan Tonga](https://www.imdb.com/name/nm7319536/), a street busker in Sydney Australia.

[image]

https://www.facebook.com/ShyanTongaMusic/photos/236239163470341

Comment: I meant in-universe, but I certainly appreciate this.

Answer (score 6):

##### One of “The Accusing Dead”

The character with facial deformities in *Mad Max: Fury Road* is one of the characters known as “[The Accusing Dead](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt1392190/characters/nm7319536)”. He is portrayed by [Shyan Tonga](https://www.imdb.com/name/nm7319536/), according to the film's credits. There is also another “The Accusing Dead” character listed in the credits, played by Crusoe Kurddal.

[image: screenshot of credits]

I discovered this by looking up the actor who played the character, Shyan Tonga, as [mentioned by TIHZHO in another post](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/260370/7957).

Comment: That's an interesting bit of info, although I don't know if it really shows what's up with him. For one thing, he isn't dead.